# direct3D 10 & 11

Tags: directx, direct3d, direct3d10

Is there a big difference (in the way of coding, ...) between the direct3d sdk 10 and 11, like "it was" between direct3d 9 and 10 ?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Not at all, philosophy and D3D10 concepts stay the same! Most of the difference is that D3D11 introduces some new cool features on top of the D3D10 core:

- two new shader stages for tesselation purpose
- compute shader stage for doing GPGPU
- dynamic shader linkage
- multithreading (immediate and deferred rendering context)
- feature levels (for targeting downlevel hardware like D3D10.x and D3D9-class GPUs)
- byte address and structured buffers
- new HLSL intrinsics (popcount, bitreversal etc)
- ...

Check out the [DXSDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=3021d52b-514e-41d3-ad02-438a3ba730ba) !

Comment: Thank you for your answer !! that's what I wanted to know.